# what's the purpose of loop at the end of go runtime main

Tags: go

when I read the runtime source, I find this code at the end of [runtime/proc.go func main](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/da2773fe3e2f6106634673a38dc3a6eb875fe7d8/src/runtime/proc.go#L272-L276)

```golang
exit(0)
for {
    var x *int32
    *x = 0
}
```

I check the history of the file.
I find that from the *c-impl*, it already is.  [runtime/proc.c](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/c007ce824d9a4fccb148f9204e04c23ed2984b71/src/runtime/proc.c#L290-L292)

```c
runtime·exit(0);
for(;;)
    *(int32*)runtime·main = 0;
```

It confuses me.

1. Why there are some code after `exit`?
2. When the code will be executed?
3. It will panic directly, so Why it need a `for-loop`?

Comment: Such questions should be asked on golang-nuts as the question and the answer do not provide actionable knowhow to write Go programs.

Answer (score 1):

The [comments on the commit](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/c81a0ed3c50606d1ada0fd9b571611b3687c90e1#r11979185) give two reasons...

1. If exit is not implemented properly, dereferencing a null pointer will crash the program.
2. A `for` loop with no condition is a [terminating statement](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Terminating_statements), though I don't understand why this is necessary.